# R: df header columns are ordinal ranking and spread across columns for each observation

Tags: r

I have a questionnaire data that look like below:

```
   items no_stars1  no_stars2   no_stars3   average satisfied   bad
1     A         1           0           0         0         0     1
2     B         0           1           0         1         0     0
3     C         0           0           1         0         1     0
4     D         0           1           0         0         1     0
5     E         0           0           1         1         0     0
6     F         0           0           1         0         1     0
7     G         1           0           0         0         0     1
```

Basically, the header columns (no. of stars rating and satisfactory) are ordinal ranking for each Items. I would like to summarize the no_stars(col 2:4) and satisfactory(col 5:7) into one column so that the output would look like this :

```
   items    no_stars    satisfactory    
1     A         1           1           
2     B         2           2           
3     C         3           3           
4     D         2           3           
5     E         3           2           
6     F         3           3           
7     G         1           1
```

$no_stars     <- 1 is for no_stars1, 2 for no_stars2, 3 for no_stars3

$satisfactory <- 1 is for bad, 2 for average, 3 for good

I have tried the code below

```
df$no_stars2[df$no_stars2 == 1] <- 2
df$no_stars3[df$no_stars3 == 1] <- 3

df$average[df$average == 1] <- 2
df$satisfied[df$satisfied == 1] <- 3

no_stars <- df$no_stars1 + df$no_stars2 + df$no_stars3
satisfactory <- df$bad + df$average + df$satisfied

tidy_df <- data.frame(df$Items, no_stars, satisfactory)
tidy_df
```

Is there any function in R that can do the same thing? or
anyone got better and simpler solution ?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just use `max.col` and set preferences:

```
starsOrder<-c("no_stars1","no_stars2","no_stars3")
satOrder<-c("bad","average","satisfied")
data.frame(items=df$items,no_stars=max.col(df[,starsOrder]),
            satisfactory=max.col(df[,satOrder]))
#  items no_stars satisfactory
#1     A        1            1
#2     B        2            2
#3     C        3            3
#4     D        2            3
#5     E        3            2
#6     F        3            3
#7     G        1            1
```

Comment: I considered that approach, but if you reread the op's post, the ordering they want isn't the same as the ordering of the variables. You would need to reorder the variables for `max.col()` to work. You have satisfactory of bad to be coded as 3 when the op wants it to be 1.

Comment: Tx for noticing it. It just suffices to change the column order to fix it.

Comment: Correct. That's why I stuck with a more verbose, yet less elegant option so as to not confuse the op.

Comment: I made it more general letting the user set the ranking of preferences.

Comment: Indeed. There are many ways to do the same thing. I tend to choose more verbose options as that's generally what my colleagues prefer and tend to understand.

Answer (score 3):

Another `tidyverse` solution making use of `factor` to `integer` conversions to encode `no_stars` and `satisfactory` and spreading from wide to long twice:

```
library(tidyverse)
df %>%
    gather(no_stars, v1, starts_with("no_stars")) %>%
    mutate(no_stars = as.integer(factor(no_stars))) %>%
    gather(satisfactory, v2, average, satisfied, bad) %>%
    filter(v1 > 0 & v2 > 0) %>%
    mutate(satisfactory = as.integer(factor(
        satisfactory, levels = c("bad", "average", "satisfied")))) %>%
    select(-v1, -v2) %>%
    arrange(items)
#  items no_stars satisfactory
#1     A        1            1
#2     B        2            2
#3     C        3            3
#4     D        2            3
#5     E        3            2
#6     F        3            3
#7     G        1            1
```

Answer (score 2):

While there may be more elegant solutions, using `dplyr::case_when()` gives you the flexibility to code things however you want:

```
library(dplyr)

df %>% 
  dplyr::mutate(
    no_stars = dplyr::case_when(
      no_stars1 == 1 ~ 1,
      no_stars2 == 1 ~ 2,
      no_stars3 == 1 ~ 3)
    , satisfactory = dplyr::case_when(
      average   == 1 ~ 2,
      satisfied == 1 ~ 3,
      bad       == 1 ~ 1)
  )
# items no_stars1 no_stars2 no_stars3 average satisfied bad no_stars satisfactory
# 1     A         1         0         0       0         0   1        1            1
# 2     B         0         1         0       1         0   0        2            2
# 3     C         0         0         1       0         1   0        3            3
# 4     D         0         1         0       0         1   0        2            3
# 5     E         0         0         1       1         0   0        3            2
# 6     F         0         0         1       0         1   0        3            3
# 7     G         1         0         0       0         0   1        1            1
```

Comment: Why are you using `dplyr::` if you are loading dplyr anyway?

Comment: Habit of writing code for packages (so I don't have to import everything) as well as clarity, as within my company we use many packages and it helps people to know what functions come from where.

Comment: so why import dplyr then?

Comment: Like I mentioned, for clarity and in this case also for the op. Also, I prefer to load packages at the beginning of my code so as to throw an error for the user 
that they are missing a package before they get into any of the code itself. I find it causes much less confusing among the people I work with to throw errors early and loud. I can remove it if it's that much of a distraction.

Answer (score 1):

```
dat%>%
   replace(.==1,NA)%>%
   replace_na(setNames(as.list(names(.)),names(.)))%>%
   replace(.==0,NA)%>%
   mutate(s=coalesce(!!!.[2:4]),
          no_stars=as.numeric(factor(s,unique(s))),
          t=coalesce(!!!.[5:7]),
          satisfactory=as.numeric(factor(t,unique(t))))%>%
   select(items,no_stars,satisfactory)

  items no_stars satisfactory
1     A        1            1
2     B        2            2
3     C        3            3
4     D        2            3
5     E        3            2
6     F        3            3
7     G        1            1
```

Answer (score 1):

using `apply` and `match` :

```
data.frame(
  items        = df1$items,
  no_stars     = apply(df1[2:4], 1, match, x=1),
  satisfactory = apply(df1[c(7,5:6)], 1, match, x=1))

#   items no_stars satisfactory
# 1     A        1            1
# 2     B        2            2
# 3     C        3            3
# 4     D        2            3
# 5     E        3            2
# 6     F        3            3
# 7     G        1            1
```

**data**

```
df1 <- read.table(header=TRUE,stringsAsFactors=FALSE,text="
   items no_stars1  no_stars2   no_stars3   average satisfied   bad
1     A         1           0           0         0         0     1
2     B         0           1           0         1         0     0
3     C         0           0           1         0         1     0
4     D         0           1           0         0         1     0
5     E         0           0           1         1         0     0
6     F         0           0           1         0         1     0
7     G         1           0           0         0         0     1")
```